# How to get a list of tables that has updated values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

.Hi everyone, I need a little help on coming up with a query that lists all tables whose data was updated from a certain date to present.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

TIA!

Addt'l info:

This is the query that I have so far:

```
Select distinct OBJECT_NAME(object_id) As TableName
From sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
Where user_updates > 0
And last_user_update > cast('07/17/2012' as datetime)
order by TableName
```

I wanted to get all the tables that had its data updated or new data inserted from 07/17/2012 to present.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't done a ton of work with SQL Server since leaving my last DBA job several years ago, instead I focus more on MySQL but I had to do something similar back then and found this article helpful. Hopefully it sheds some light...

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/

Comment: .Thank you for this. 
I tried using this a while ago but I'm having a hard time modifying the query to make make it work as needed.

Comment: Can you post the query? That'd be helpful for the community to see so we can better try and assist.